# How to fix screen glitching when trying to "try or install ubuntu" in grub?

Tags: boot, grub2, gnu-screen

Screen glitch:

[image: Screen photo]

I have an old lenovo g450 laptop. I am trying to install ubuntu in it using a bootable usb drive. There is no windows in it. I entered grub and clicked "try or install ubuntu". But then after the underscore blinking on top left corner of screen, it shows this glitching (refer the image).
I went to this [link](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-in/000123893/manual-nomodeset-kernel-boot-line-option-for-linux-booting) and did the nomodeset command after splash, but it is still showing the screen glitch.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? If nomodeset does not work there really is noting else. What is confusing is how you have a grub menu on a new install on a PC that has no OS.

Comment: @David I just grabbed as Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop & booted on a `lenovo g560 (i5m-480, 4gb, i915)` and I get to see grub which asks the *maybe-ubiquity` like option of Try or Install option..  Alas we have no clues as to what Ubuntu product, what release, nor what actual installer & thus what  the expected outcome is.. (*let alone what ISO checks etc were performed*) as you asked.

Comment: Yes if the version had been in the question I would have ignored it.